# Make image fit inside button in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I want to fit the image inside the `UIButton` using storyboard but not able to do so. Can somebody tell me how to do that.

Comment: Do you only want to do it using storyboard or via code is fine too?

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the Image Via EdgeInset Property via Programatically or Via StoryBoard.

[image]

Change It Image.

[image]

And Adjust Top Left Bottom Right to make Image to Fit.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to do like:

```
myLikesButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right);
```

Or by using

```
 [self.btn setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 6, 6, 6)];
```

The inset or outset margins for the rectangle around the button’s image.